# SQL Automation Qry error

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I'm following this example here ([Query to Combine Data from 3 different Data View Tables](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/373185/query-to-combine-data-from-3-different-data-view-tables)) and when I try to run the ClickDataView SQL to a data extension I get and err. My DE (ClickDataView) has a field LinkName. Some of the values records will have a comma in the linkName which may be cause an err

Comment: I think you're missing something in your question.  Like your query and the error message text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling data from data views is sometimes erratic because specific fields in the data views have "interesting" content that will show up only when running in production.

So when tried on "real production data", perfectly functional queries often stumble because of the nature of the field content.

I have been running similar queries in many orgs for a long time, and fixed errors whenever they occured - So with a high degree of certitude, the following changes should stabilize your queries. In case this does not help, reduce fields in your query one by one, until it works. The last one you removed before it worked is the culprit. The general approach of sanitizing the input can be copied from these two examples:

In _click, I've found "linkContent" to be sometimes be longer than 4000 chars, fix:

```
AccountID
, OYBAccountID
, JobID
, ListID
, BatchID
, SubscriberID
, SubscriberKey
, EventDate
, Domain
, URL
, LinkName
, LEFT(LinkContent, 4000) AS LinkContent
, IsUnique
, TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
, TriggeredSendCustomerKey
FROM _Click]]
```

other notorious example, _bounce, where special chars (commas, semicolons, quotes), as well as lengths etc can break the query with real data.

```
SELECT AccountID
, OYBAccountID
, JobID
, ListID
, BatchID
, SubscriberID
, SubscriberKey
, EventDate
, IsUnique
, Domain
, BounceCategoryID
, BounceCategory
, BounceSubcategoryID
, BounceSubcategory
, BounceTypeID
, BounceType
/* replace commas and semicolons with -, double quotes with single quotes */
, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(SMTPBounceReason, 4000), CHAR(44),'-'), CHAR(34),CHAR(39)), CHAR(59),'-') AS SMTPBounceReason
, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(SMTPMessage, 4000), CHAR(44),'-'), CHAR(34),CHAR(39)), CHAR(59),'-') AS SMTPMessage
, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SMTPCode, CHAR(44),'-'), CHAR(34),CHAR(39)) , CHAR(59),'-') AS SMTPCode
, TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
, TriggeredSendCustomerKey
FROM _bounce
```

reference for special chars:https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6022/sql-server-char-function-and-reference-guide/